# How to transfer PCollection to a normal List

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a PCollection as a result of a pipeline after doing Bigquery processing, now I want to use some part of that data separate from the pipeline. How do I transfer a PCollection to a List so that I can iterate through it and use the content.

Am I doing something wrong conceptually ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are done with data processing inside your Dataflow pipeline, you'd likely want to write the data into a persistent storage, such as files in Cloud Storage (GCS), a table in BigQuery, etc.

You can then consume the data outside Dataflow, for example, to read it into a List. Obviously, it would need to fit into memory for that specific action.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is creating "side outputs" (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do) that is another PCollection that you create together with your main process so in the end you will have 2 PCollections as result of your BQ process.

Just ensure that on your process function you create a condition to add elements to side output collection. Something like this:

```
public final void processElement(final ProcessContext context) throws Exception {
  context.output(bqProcessResult);
  if (condition) {
    context.sideOutput(myFilterTag, bqProcessResult);
  }
}
```

The result of that process is not a PCollection but a PCollectionTuple so you just have to do the following:

```
PCollectionTuple myTuples = previous process using the function above...;
PCollection<MyType> bqCollection = myTuples.get(bqTag);
PCollection<MyType> filteredCollection = myTuples.get(myFilterTag);
```